# Checking connection to two servers in shell using nested loops

Tags: shell, docker, sh, alpine-linux

I have docker environment defined in docker-compose.
It has 3 containers. Two with databases and a third with cli script interpreter.

3rd container has to wait for 2 db containers to accept connections.

It was quite simple when I had just one db container.
3rd container ( Alpine based ) entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
while ! nc -z $MYSQL_HOST $MYSQL_PORT; do
    echo "Waiting for MySQL to accept connections ..."
    sleep 0.2
done
echo "MYSQL ready"

exec "$@"
```

Now with the second container I would like to solve this using nested loop but since posix shell does not in general support arrays I don't know exactly how.

The general idea is to create a string with host1:port1 separated by space

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVERS="DB1_HOST:DB1_PORT DB2_HOST:DB2_PORT"
```

Loop through it by creating items using space ( I think IFS=' ' ) than use DB:PORT to check connection using `nc` and remove DB:PORT from SERVERS variable when connection becomes possible.

My main concern is that I don't know how to remove DB:PORT from within a SERVERS variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a refactoring of the answer you posted which avoids some idiosyncrasies and inefficiencies.

```
#!/bin/sh
: ${MYSQL_HOST?must not be unset}
: ${MYSQL_PORT?must not be unset}
: ${REDIS_HOST?must not be unset}
: ${REDIS_PORT?must not be unset}

# avoid uppercase for private variables
# avoid gratuitous non-portable newline
# pad with surrounding spaces
servers=" MYSQL_HOST:MYSQL_PORT REDIS_HOST:REDIS_PORT "

while true; do
    for server in $servers; do
        db_host=${server%:*}
        db_port=${server#*:}
        if nc -z "$db_host" "$db_port"; then
            # Show diagnostic messages on stderr
            echo "$0: Host '$db_host' started accepting connections" >&2
            servers="${servers#* $db_host:$db_port } ${servers% $db_host:$db_port *}"
        else
            echo "$0: Waiting for host '$db_host' to start accepting connections on port '$db_port' ..." >&2
        fi
    done
    case $servers in
      *[! ]*) ;;
      *) break
    esac
    sleep 0.4
done
```

Using a single space-separated string to loop over is a bit hacky, but at least we avoid external processes to manipulate the list of servers here.  In the absence of array variables, there is no really good way to selectively drop some servers and keep others.  Also, because of the space padding, the `servers` string won't necessarily be empty when we have removed all servers, so we check inside the loop if it contains non-space characters.

It would probably make more sense to accept the servers as command-line arguments (perhaps then directly in host:port form) than to require the caller to set multiple variables (let alone then use uppercase for those variables).  Then looping over `"$@"` would perhaps also make manipulating the list of servers simpler.

I'll point you to http://shellcheck.net/ which diagnoses many of these errors without human intervention, and http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo which points out some common antipatterns.  The POSIX `sh` spec on [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) explains many of the constructs in the code above.  The [Bash manual section on parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) obviously documents Bash, but might also be useful as a secondary source.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values as function arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh

sqlup() {
    for server do
        IFS=: read -r host port

        while ! nc -z "$host" "$port"; do
            printf 'Waiting for MySQL to accept connections...\n'
            sleep 0.2
        done
    done

    printf 'MySQL ready\n'
}

sqlup DB1_HOST:DB1_PORT DB2_HOST:DB2_PORT # ...
exec "$@"
```

Comment: I've posted an answer below.

Comment: Your solution has a lot of bad practices, but ok.

Comment: I would appreciate pointing them out. I've seen @triplee answer and code looks much better than mine but I still don't know about what bad practices are you talking about.

Comment: just a small example: `value=$(eval "echo \$$VAR")`. There is no reason why that can't just be `value=$VAR`.

Comment: It can't because in this case $VAR holds "name" of the variable being checked.

Comment: Then just `value=${!VAR}`

Answer (score 0):

Working solution. Testing on Linux Alpine 3.7 using ASH

If anyone knows why script was breaking ( check line starting with # in code, than please post a comment ~thanks )

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSQL_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST:-3}
MYSQL_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT:-3}
REDIS_HOST=${REDIS_HOST:-3}
REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT:-3}

REQ_VARS="MYSQL_HOST\nMYSQL_PORT\nREDIS_HOST\nREDIS_PORT"

printf "$REQ_VARS" | while IFS='' read -r VAR
do
    value=$(eval "echo \$$VAR")
    if [[ ${value} == 3 ]]; then
        echo "Error: Variable '$VAR' cannot be undefined"
        exit 1
    fi
done

SERVERS="MYSQL_HOST:MYSQL_PORT\nREDIS_HOST:REDIS_PORT"

while test ! -z "$SERVERS"
do
    for server in $(printf "$SERVERS"); do
        while IFS=: read HOST PORT; do
            DB_HOST=$(eval "echo \$$HOST")
            DB_PORT=$(eval "echo \$$PORT")

            if nc -z $DB_HOST $DB_PORT; then
                echo "Host '$DB_HOST' started accepting connections"

                # When removing last server from SERVERS script was terminating
                if [ "$(printf "$SERVERS" | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]; then
                    SERVERS=$(printf "$SERVERS" | grep -iv "$HOST:$PORT")
                else
                    SERVERS=""
                fi

                continue
            fi

            echo "Waiting for host '$DB_HOST' to start accepting connections on port '$DB_PORT' ..."

        done <<EOF
$(printf "$server")
EOF

    done

    # Wait 0.4 of the second before checking again
    sleep 0.4
done
```

Comment: You might want to explore `${variable?must not be unset}`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find anything on google. Please share correct search phrase. Thanks

Comment: See separate answer now. Incidentally, your code has a bug: if you have a servers whose name is a substrings of another, you remove both when the shorter one responds. (`host:11` is a substring of `otherhost:111`)